# Australian PR/Indonesian Passport - Do I need a visa to go to Korea?

Tags: visas, south-korea, visa-free-entry, australian-residents

I am an Indonesian passport holder who has Australian residency. I'm planning to go to Korea (ICN) through Taiwan (TPE), but I won't leave Taipei airport the first time around.

From my research and [this website](http://aus-sydney.mofa.go.kr/english/as/aus-sydney/visa/issuance/index.jsp), it states that passport holders from countries that are NOT granted visa-free entry to Korea, but hold either an Australian, US, Canadian, NZ visa AND are transiting FROM/TO the countries mentioned above through Korea are eligible for 30 day visa-free entry to Korea.

My plan is as follows:

- SYD-TPE (not leaving)-ICN
- ICN - TPE (stays for 2/3 days) - SYD

http://aus-sydney.mofa.go.kr/english/as/aus-sydney/visa/issuance/index.jsp

> Transit tourists bound for another country
>
> Eligible countries
>   Applicable to all countries (save forMacedonia, Cuba, Syria, Sudan and Iran) that are not granted visa-free entry into Korea.
>   Applicable to…
>   Persons holding a visa (re-entry permit, permanent residency, etc.) to enter >the U.S. (including Guam and Saipan), Canada, Australia, or New Zealand(hereinafter referred to as "the four advanced countries")
>   1) who transit through Korea to go to one of the four advanced countries.
>   2) who stay in one of the four advanced countries and take a direct flight from >the country to Korea to go to a country of origin or a third country.

My question is:

What counts as a 'Direct Flight'? If I stop by TPE but not exiting, am I eligible for visa-free entry to Korea?

Answer (score 3):

You're not transiting in ICN, you're **going to** ICN. Your flight is a round trip SYD-ICN-SYD, which makes ICN the destination, and not a transit.

If you were doing say SYD-ICN-PEK and back, that'd work. But as it stands now, your itinerary precludes you from getting the visa-free entry.

Comment: What if I'm going for SYD-ICN-TPE-SYD?

Comment: It might work, IF you are indeed entering Taiwan (and not just transiting there).